# Coloring datapoints in categories - Stripchart R

Tags: r, plot, colors, stripchart

I'm a new programmer in R, making an attempt at a StripChart (I have too few data points in each category to display my data as a boxplot). I would like to get my stripchart categories to be colored individually, rather than coloring each individual data point separately.

My data are a bit odd, but here's a snippet of them, as from a .csv file:

```
 NO3_W    NO3_S   NO3_N   NO3_E    NH4_W    NH4_S    NH4_N   NH4_E
109.3820 17.36120 25.7474 7.05187 218.0470 17.73920 41.67180 4.68764
94.7625  19.53920 17.6870      NA 215.1450  8.42217 24.21860      NA
125.1190  6.09643  5.4894      NA 306.4350  6.09589  9.38554      NA
116.9880 52.04350      NA      NA 229.9380 97.87880       NA      NA
39.1758        NA      NA      NA  91.0918       NA       NA      NA
```

To reiterate, I want to create a stripchart with each column of data as a separate category, in which each category is colored distinctly.

[image]

Here is the code that I've been using, simplified from the figure I included.

```
ChemColor = c("green","blue","red","orange","purple","hotpink","dodgerblue","orchid1")

SecColor = c("darkgrey","darkblue","gray","black")

stripchart(Sectors, pch = 21, bg = ChemColor, 
    las = 1, log = "x", xaxt = "n", col = rep(SecColor)); 
    eaxis(1, at = c(0.1,1,10,100), 
    labels = c("0.100","1.00","10.0","100"), font.axis = 2)
```

Thanks you for any help you can offer!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by strip chart. Can you post an example image? Also if you can show what the problem is with the code that you posted, people might be able to provide ideas.

Comment: Thanks for responding. To clarify, I mean literally the plot generated by the call "stripchart()". It's similar to a box and whisker, but works for smaller numbers of data points. 

The image is included as a link (http://i.stack.imgur.com/qFOry.png) since I'm a new user to stackoverflow. If you follow the link, you can see that the points in the chart are oddly colored --mostly grey, and not distinct between the horizontal categories. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks pretty easy to deal with using long tables and ggplot2. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for ways that you can add the data directly to your question.